# How to increase the size of vuetify v-switch

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to increase the size of whole vuetify v-switch component,as it is not listed in v-switch [api](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-switch/#props)
i tried to change the sass variables but it change the entire switches that the application have
[click to see the current size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inH3z.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you are changing SASS variables, it **must** affect all the elements in the application.

To change the only one `v-switch`, you can write something like:

```html
<template>
  <v-switch
    v-model="switch1"
    class="custom-switch"
    :label="`Switch 1: ${switch1.toString()}`"
  ></v-switch>
</template>

<style>
.v-input--switch__track {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 29px;
  top: -2px;
}

.v-input--switch__thumb {
  left: 6px;
}

.custom-switch .v-input__slot .v-label {
  left: 6px !important
}

.v-input--selection-controls__ripple {
  height: 0;
  width: 0
}
</style>
```

[CodePen demo is here.](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/rNKBObr)